# Opening a new window with a PyQt5 .ui file causes a RESTART: SHELL

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

Using the script attached, I'm trying to open a new window using a .ui file I made in PyQt5 designer. Main() loads fine but Single() casues the restart. When I make the function instead load Main() again, it works and just shows the same window as expected. Any ideas as to why the second ui is not loading? There are no errors in the output and the only thing shown is "RESTART: SHELL"

`

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
import sys

class singleVideo(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(singleVideo, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('singleVideo.ui', self)

def loadSingleVideoUI():
    print("click!")

    window = singleVideo()
    window.show()

class Main(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('Main.ui', self)

        self.Single.clicked.connect(lambda:loadSingleVideoUI())
    



app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Main()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`

I tried looking online but the only thing I could find were unanswered forum questions.
I tried asking on a Python Discord server but I only got one response telling me to get rid of the QApplication instance created in the function as there can only be one instance (which I've done)
I even tried asking ChatGPT thinking that it could at least point me somewhere but it didn't help much either.
Now I'm trying to ask here.

Comment: Typo: either use the correct indentation for `singleVideo` (and call `self.singleVideo`) or remove `self` from its arguments.

Comment: Works except now it just keeps opening Main() instead of Single()

Comment: You probably mistyped or overwrote something, but we cannot help you with a valid [mre].

Comment: Do you need the files too? Or just the updated code?

Comment: I just noticed that you mistyped the code in the original question (for future reference, **always** check the post preview and its code syntax before submitting). It seems like the other class actually loads a different ui file, so either you overwrote the ui files (or are using a wrong path) or you did something wrong. I suggest you to: 1. check that the two ui files are actually different and their paths correctly point to the right ui you want to load; 2. [edit] your post and provide the new code after modifications.

Comment: Is the code fixed now? It runs without errors (except for the problem with it opening Main() instead of Single() ) The two Ui files are different as if I load singleVideo() first it works, there is only a problem with the switching of files

Comment: It does not load the wrong window, it just creates the new one but never shows it because you're not keeping any reference. I **specifically** told you what to do: use the proper name in the connection, or change the indentation level by making the function a method. We cannot help you if you don't follow what's being suggested to you.

Comment: My bad, I misinterpreted your previous comment as you telling me to double-check the filenames. It's solved now, thank you.